# mysql query to match the name but to avoid the uid not working

Tags: mysql

hello i am trying to match a group name with uid of particular names

```
    group_name  sort    date    uid
    friends       0     2011    gname
    family        1     2011    gname1
    following     4     2011    gname2
    acqaintances  3     2011    gname3
```

i want that whatever user enters to create a new group , it can't be the default group.and rest of the groups can be same as they would have a unqiue uid , i took these uid gname,gname1,gname2,game3 common for all. any help on this ? i tried a query that didnt worked as it showed results even if user enters anything apart from these four groups

here it is

> select group_name from groups where group_name="example" and uid='gname'
>   or uid='gname1' or uid='gname2' or uid='gname3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parentheses to make sure the and/or condition gets grouped correctly:

```
select group_name from groups where group_name="example" and
  (uid='gname' or uid='gname1' or uid='gname2' or uid='gname3')
```

In your original query, `and` binds more tightly than `or`, so you end up effectively doing:

```
select group_name from groups where (group_name="example" and uid='gname')
  or uid='gname1' or uid='gname2' or uid='gname3'
```